# Cant refresh UITableView inside UIViewController

Tags: objective-c

Newbie :(

Tweaking my way through tutorials but 36 hours can't figure this one

Example 1.h

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSArray     *userList;      // the current list of users
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray       *userList;
- (void) updateTable:(NSArray *)data;
- (void) fetchData;
@end
```

Example 1.m

```
- (void) updateTable:(NSArray *)data {
    self.userList = data;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

This works, the asynchronous XML object returns an array with the selector updateTable and the table updates.

But when I make the view a UIViewController the table doesn't update

Example 2.h

```
@class xmlGetStories;

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
        UITableView *tableView;
        NSArray *userList;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;    
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *userList;
- (void) updateTable:(NSArray *)data;
- (void) fetchData;
@end
```

Example 2.m

```
- (void) updateTable:(NSArray *)data {
    self.userList = data;
    NSLog(@"updateTable sees this data: %@", userList);
    //[self.tableView reloadData];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

updateTable executes and the data is passed across alright but the table doesn't refresh. I realise that it's something to do with the way I'm addressing the table as it's part of a UIViewController rather than a direct UITableViewController. But I thought that

```
 UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

wired in the table. I have another testbed example where example two works if I hardcode the array contents into the AppDelegate.

I have tried

```
[FirstViewController reloadData];
[FirstViewController.tableView reloadData];
```

Neither work.

Brain dead looking at code. Hopefully it's something simple.

TIA

Comment: could you paste the output of NSLog(@"%@",tableView); in updateTable:

Comment: Did you connect the datasource and delegate outlets of the table in interface builder to the controller?

Comment: @Saltymule. Aha, no I hadn't... good thinking. But after dataSource and delegate to File's Owner in FirstView.xib the app crashes with Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FirstViewController tableView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9403c60'

Comment: Doh! I had commented out @synthasise tableView while trying to solve the issue so ignore the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause is that `tableView` is `nil`. Make sure you have wired it in IB.